# How to configure different limits and requests for CPU/memory in Cloud Run for GKE pods?

Tags: memory-management, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

In Cloud Run for GKE I can see only a single parameter to define CPU/memory allocation. And it applies it to both requests and limits. Is it possible to configure CPU/Memory requests and limits separately?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can in fact configure both `requests` and `limits` for Cloud Run on GKE services. However, this is not available in the `gcloud run deploy` CLI (yet).

Instead, you need to write a YAML manifest for a Knative Service (a.k.a. KService) and specify requests/limits just like a Kubernetes app and you can use `gcloud alpha run replace` command to deploy this manifest (like `kubectl apply`).

There's an example at https://knative.tips/pod-config/cpu-memory-resources/ I'm pasting here for posterity:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 512M
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1Gi
```